# Nested HashMap with Array, JAVA

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following hashMap:

```
{"success":true,
 "message":"Profile retrieved successfully",
 "data":{
     "address":[{
        "objectId":"6ItcdQGBFu",
        "street":"6782 NW 102nd St",
        "aptSuite":"782",
        "state":"FL",
        "zipCode":"33762",
        "city":"Brickell",
        "type":"Home"},{
        "objectId":"yyRA9M2gk1", 
        "street":"7828 NW Boston Rb",
        "state":"Massachusetts",
        "zipCode":"33178",
        "city":"Boston",
        "type":"Office"}
     ]
    }
}
```

If I want to access the "message", I would write the following code:

```
    object.get("message");
```

Or if I wanna print it:

```
    object.get("message").toString();
```

I would like to know how can I iterate and access through the "address" objects.

Comment: We have no idea, because we don't know the type of the object at the key "data".

Comment: That is not a hashmap. That is a JSON string.

Comment: I think you should use JSON parsers for this kind of object, that I will help you on this, please check Jackson lib

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a bunch of nested HashMaps (and "address" points to a list with one item, according to your example), you could access a value in the message through

```
object.get("data").get("address").get(0).get("street")
```

and you could iterate through all the fields by

```
HashMap<String, String> addressObj = object.get("data").get("address").get(0);
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : addressObj.keySet()) {
    String key = entrey.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: sounds reasonable, if that's the case, the variable "object" should be declared like this?

Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList>>> object